# Why logo and Google map won't show up on this page

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, graphical-logo

I don't understand why the logo and Google map suddenly went missing on this [page](http://www.unpaidfines.com.au/). There's supposed to be a logo on the top left and the code is there even if you look at the source code. At the back end, here's the code placed on the header:

```
<div class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img  src="<?php echo bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></div>
```

The image for the logo is also present on the directory and is not missing so it can't be due to a missing file or wrong image link.

And yet it won't show up.

I've checked the CSS stylesheet and compared it with a [similar site](http://www.drink-driving-lawyers.com.au/) with the logo showing up fine on the top left and everything is fine.

Add to this, there's supposed to be a Google map somewhere between the boxes for "Can I Afford a Lawyer" and "I Have a Valid Reason for My Unpaid Fines" and the codes for that are also properly in place. But for some reason the map simply just vanished. I checked the back end of this page and the code is also properly in place (I compared it again with the [similar site](http://www.drink-driving-lawyers.com.au/) where the map is showing up fine and everything is in place).

What could be causing this? Am I looking at the wrong places (stylesheet and header codes)? We're using Wordpress.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

---

Additional code for the map as requested (not sure if I overdid it but I believe these are the codes involved):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {



// var
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

// vars
var args = {
    zoom        : 8,
    center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

// create map               
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

// add a markers reference
map.markers = [];

// add markers
$markers.each(function(){

    add_marker( $(this), map );

});

// center map
center_map( map );

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

// var
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

// create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map
});

// add to array
map.markers.push( marker );

// if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
if( $marker.html() )
{
    // create info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content     : $marker.html()
    });

    // show info window when marker is clicked
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        infowindow.open( map, marker );

    });
}

}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

// vars
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// loop through all markers and create bounds
$.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

    bounds.extend( latlng );

});

// only 1 marker?
if( map.markers.length == 1 )
{
    // set center of map
    map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
    map.setZoom( 16 );
}
else
{
    // fit to bounds
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
}

}

/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.acf-map').each(function(){

    render_map( $(this) );

});

});

})(jQuery);
</script>  
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

            jQuery(window).load(function(){   

               var Height=jQuery('.other').height(); 
              jQuery(".acf-map").height(Height);


            });

            jQuery(window).resize(function() {

               var Height=jQuery('.other').height(); 
                jQuery(".acf-map").height(Height);


            });



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the browser inspector, you can see that there is a style that is being added to the wrapper for the site logo:

```
.site-title, .site-description {
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    position: absolute;
}
```

That `clip` rule is causing your problem.  Remove that rule from your styles, and it shows up.

It appears you are using some plugin or something like "autoptimize" - could that be causing the problem?

As far as the map - that element is completely empty.  The only issue apparent is a notice from Google Maps:

```
"Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required"
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The clip rule seems to have been set up by the autooptimize plugin. I tried deactivating that plugin but it didn't solve the problem. Further, we're using the same plugin on other sites and everything is working fine with the others. The map is even more mind-boggling...

Answer (score 0):

regarding your image you should be using [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)

```
<img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/images/logo.png" />
```

Comment: I've included the codes for the map. But I truly believe the issue has nothing to do with the codes since the same codes exist on the similar site and the map is showing up fine there.